# Segmentation Fault during delete []

Tags: c++, c++11

I am building a game and I need to store in a dynamic array a player,  every time that a player is created. I built a small piece of code to try it and I get a `segmentation fault` when I try to `delete` the table to insert the third player. I just can't realize why that happens: the `header` file is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Player

{

    private:
        string PlayerName;
        int PlayerScore;
    public:
        Player();       
        Player(string name, int s);     
        ~Player() {};       
        string getPlayerName()  {return PlayerName;}
        int getPlayerScore() {return PlayerScore;}
        void setPlayerName(string name){PlayerName = name;}
        void setPlayerScore(int score){PlayerScore = score;}
};

class Game
{

    private:
        Player NewPlayer;
        int NPlayers;
        Player* PlayerList;
        //vector <Player> PlayerList2;
    
        
    public:
        Game();
        ~Game();
        void setNewPlayer(string, int); 
        void resizePlayerList();
        void PrintList();   
};
```

The `class` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include "I.h"

using namespace std;


    
Player::Player()
{
    PlayerName = "";
    PlayerScore = 0;
}

Player::Player(string name, int s)
{
    PlayerName = name;
    PlayerScore = s;
}       


Game::Game() 
{
    NPlayers = 0;
    PlayerList = NULL;
};
Game::~Game() {};

void Game::setNewPlayer(string str, int scr)
{
    NewPlayer = Player(str, scr);   
    resizePlayerList(); 
    PrintList();        
}


void Game::resizePlayerList() {
   
    if(NewPlayer.getPlayerName() != "No Name")
    {
            int newSize = NPlayers +1;
            
            Player* newArr = NULL;
            newArr = new Player[newSize];           
            memcpy( newArr, PlayerList, NPlayers * sizeof(Player) );            
            NPlayers = newSize;         
            delete [] PlayerList;           
            PlayerList = newArr;            
            PlayerList[NPlayers-1] = NewPlayer;
    } 
   
}


void Game::PrintList()
{
    Player player;
    //cout << NPlayers << endl;
    for(int i= 0; i < NPlayers; i++)
    {
        player = PlayerList[i];     
        cout << player.getPlayerName() << " " <<  player.getPlayerScore() << endl;  
    }

}
```

The `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "I.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Game NewGame;
    NewGame.setNewPlayer("Peter",20);
    NewGame.setNewPlayer("Someone Someone",30);
    NewGame.setNewPlayer("Someone else",40);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In modern C++, you should use containers and smart pointers, rather than try to manage that yourself (because it's hard, and you'll make bugs... like you did here... using `memcpy` on an object that cannot be `memcpy`'d).

Comment: "I need to store in a dynamic array a player" -> `std::vector`

Comment: if you do manually manage memory you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three, but you really shouldn't do it manually

Comment: `std::vector<Player> playerList;`  then resizing is as trivial as `playerList.push_back(NewPlayer);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from here:

```
memcpy(newArr, PlayerList, NPlayers * sizeof(Player));
```

You **cannot** copy classes in this manner, unless they are [Trivially Copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (originally said [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType), but as Yksisarvinen points out in the comments, [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is not quite that restrictive). You can fix this by using a loop to copy over the data instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NPlayers; ++i) {
    newArr[i] = std::move(PlayerList[i]);
}
```

The better option though, is to use a `std::vector<Player>`, then the entire resize function can be simplified to:

```
void Game::resizePlayerList() {
    if (NewPlayer.getPlayerName() != "No Name") {
        PlayerList.push_back(std::move(NewPlayer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or the `<algorithm>` function `std::move` instead of the loop.

Comment: @aschepler, honestly didn't even know that was thing. That's good to know for future reference :)